# Python's / and // operators on 2.7.4

Tags: python, operators

I am new to Python and I started studying the basics. I am a C++ guy so the // operator was something new. According with a book that I am reading:

```
>> 4/2
2.0
>> 2/4
0.5
>> 5//4
2
>> 2//4
0
```

The problem is that when I write `5//4` the result is 1,when I write `4/2` the result is 2 and not 2.0 and when I write `2/4` the result is 0 . I have to write `2.0/4.0' to have 0.5 as the result. Is these author's mistakes or am I doing something wrong?

I am using Python 2.7.4, [GCC 4.7.3] on linux2

Comment: Does the book say what version of python it uses?

Comment: @JoshLee I can't find it, I don't know if he mentioned it but the book has been published on 2013, so I suppose 2.5 or newer.

Comment: From the result shown for `4/2`, it looks like the book is using Python 3.x. However in both Python 2.x and 3.x `5//4` is `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2.x, the default division operator is "Classic division". This means that `/`, when used with integer operators will result in integer division similar to C++ or java [i.e. `4/3 = 1`].

In Python 3.x, this is changed. There, `/` refers to "True division" [`4/3 = 1.3333..`], whereas `//` is used to request "Classic/Floor division".

If you want enable "True division" in Python 2.7, you can use `from __future__ import division` in your code.

Source: [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

For example:

```
>>> 4/3
1
>>> 4//3
1
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 4/3
1.3333333333333333
>>> 4//3
1
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference occurs in case of `Python 3.x` . 
In Python 3.0, `7 / 2` will return **3.5** and `7 // 2` will return **3**. The operator `/` is `floating point division`, and the operator `//` is `floor division` or `integer division`.

But in case of `Python 2.x` there won't be any difference and the text is wrong I believe, here is the output I am getting.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on 
win32 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 4/2
2
>>> 2/4
0
>>> 5//4
1
>>> 2//4
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `//` seems to be working correctly,

See this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) on operators.

> // = Floor Division - The division of operands where the result is the
>   quotient in which the digits after the decimal point are removed. 
>   9//2 is equal to 4 and 9.0//2.0 is equal to 4.0

for `4/2` to equal `2.0` you need to specify a float. For example : `4/float(2)` evaluates to `2.0`. The ints `4` and `2` are not already defined as `floats` when you divide.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**In python 2.7 and prior,**
there always **integer division** unless there is a float.
Both / and // are integer division in python 2.7 and prior.

```
>>>4/3
1
>>>4//3
1
>>>4/2.0
2.0
>>> 4//1.5
2.0
```

**In python 3.2 and later** 
/ is for float division and // for integer division

```
>>>4/2
2
>>>4/2.0
2.0
>>>3/2
1.5
```

So in python 2.7 if you want to return an accurate float number,the divisor **or** the divider must be float,else you will get an integer division no matter what symbol you use for division / or //.If you use a float with the // you will get an integer with .0 at the end.

In python 3.2++ if you want an integer division you use //,if you want floating division you use /.

see [this](http://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers)  for the differences between python versions.