# Specific Python 2 to Python 3 conversion headache

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pulling my hair out over this problem:

LEXPRESSION(1): `lambda x,y: [set_stri('t '+str(int(x)//int(y))),process_line()]`

LEXPRESSION(2): `lambda x,y: [set_stri('t '+str(int(x)/int(y))),process_line()]`

['-6', '3'] IS PARAMS

Lambda expression(1) evaluates int(x)//int(y) to -2 as expected.
Lambda expression(2) gets evaluated to 2.0. I have tried different ways of re-writing it. Float always robs the sign in this context. Yes, I tried float(x)/float(y), also returns 2.0.

I say "this context" because if you fire up the interpreter and create the lambda expression it outputs -2.0. But I have a crude artificial intelligence interpreter. It creates its own strings which can be interpreted and converted to speech. Above, the 't '....' is a Talk command, it speaks the results. So in the context of an eval() function, the sign always disappears for my float division. Float addition has no problem in the same exact context.

Comment: You're missing bits and have a lot of not needed info. I'm assuming `set_stri` just adds the value to a string, and `process_line()` is not necessary. I ran the function in python 3 and it returned `-2.0`.

Comment: I'm assuming this maybe has to do with the [change in division between python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093584/pythons-and-operators-on-2-7-4).  But I also have no idea what `process_line()` is doing so I don't know. But running `'t '+str(int(x)//int(y))` in my python 3 on your input gives `-2.0`

Comment: What is `set_stri`? If I just do `f1 = lambda x,y: 't '+str(int(x)//int(y))` and `f2 = lambda x,y: 't '+str(int(x)/int(y))`, then `f1('-6','3')` and `f2('-6','3')`, both values are negative. So the problem is not reproducible with this as it lays in `set_stri`

Comment: I am fairly certain, that the issue is with the custom function `set_stri()`, because `-6 / 3` produces `-2.0` and `-6 // 3` produces `-2`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their comments. I was able to solve my particular problem. I don't think it would help to describe the solution here, because it was unique to the complexity of what my 10,000 line program was doing. I do a lot of string manipulation and had to refactor some of this due to the changes Python3 made to string libraries and where functionalities reside. I also experienced an incompatibility with my pickled data structure that caused me to re-enter a bunch of data. I hope that the dust has settled and we don't need a Python4 that reformats the language again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commenters, I solved the problem. They were correct, it was something to do with the context switch to set_stri(), and then process_line(). It would be very very difficult to find out exactly why (for someone with my skill level and time willing to be spent).

I am declaring this SOLVED! I was able to eliminate the calls to (set_stri() and process_line() in this situation. The Python 2 code needs no changes to accomplish the same process. THANKS TO THE COMMENTERS !!!!